$\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ for which there are $n+1$ eigenvectors such that any $n$ of them are linearly independent.
Find $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ for which there are $n+1$ eigenvectors such that any $n$ of them are linearly independent.
Here are some of my thoughts, but I am not sure if everything is alright.
Let's imagine that $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_k$ are eigenvalues, so, for each eigenvalue we have subspaces $V_{\lambda_1}, ..., V_{\lambda_k}$. If we want any $n$ of eigenvectors to be linearly independent, it means that $n \leq \dim V_{\lambda_i}$. Moreover, we know that $\sum \dim V_{\lambda_i} \leq n$. It means that there is only one subspace $V_1$ and $\dim V_1 = n$. Furthermore, we know that $\dim V_1 = n - rk(A-\lambda_1 I)$. It means that $A = \lambda_1 I$.

Try $\phi(x) = x$ with $n=1$ and take the eigenvectors $\pm1$.

OP: I believe your proof that any $\phi$ with the given property must be a constant multiple of the identity map is correct, well done! That doesn't technically answer the question, but it should make it easy for you to construct an example that does.
